# Layout of components in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I created 3 components `Comp1.js`, `Comp2.js`, and `Comp3.js`, and I want them to appear on the page layout in the order they appear. What I did is included them in `App.js` as

```
const App = () => {
 <div className="App">
   <Comp1/>
   <Comp2/>
   <Comp3/>
 </div>
}
```

However, in this case I need to know the height of each component so that to start the next component after the previous one using CSS margins or some other way. Is there another way, where I don't have to do these calculations?

EDIT: More clarification

I don't want margins between components. Maybe I wasn't clear. In a project I am working on, I have a fixed navbar, which corresponds to Comp1 in my example above. So, Comp2 must start after Comp1, which means I need to know the height of the navbar to start Comp2 after it using margin-top in CSS, and if I used fixed position, I would need to know the height of both Comp1 and Comp2 to start Comp3 after them in the order they appear. I am wondering if there is a way where I keep the navbar fixed, but I don't have to calculate its height to start Comp2 after it

Comment: So you want to know how to calculate the height of a component?

Comment: See updated question, please.

Comment: I assume you're using bootstrap? I've never had to calculate height to layout a page. Are you using bootstrap's grid system?

Comment: Not really. Just normal CSS. For Comp1 I use the properties `position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the margins between the components, may be you can apply some common class to all components.

```
    <Comp1 className="marginClass"/>
    <Comp2 className="marginClass"/>
    <Comp3 className="marginClass"/>
```

Comment: I don't want margins between components. Maybe I wasn't clear. In a project I am working on, I have a fixed navbar, which corresponds to Comp1 in my example above. So, Comp2 must start after Comp1, which means I need to know the height of the navbar to start Comp2 after it. I am wondering if there is a way where I keep the navbar fixed, but I don't have to calculate its height to start Comp2 after it.

Answer (score 0):

To make your Comp1 fixed, you dont have to calculate the height of every component
In your Comp1 component, you can apply this to your container div

```
.container {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

This way your Comp1 will be fixed to the Top,

Hope it helps

Comment: But then Comp2 must start after Comp1, which means I need to start Comp2 after the height of Comp1, because Comp1 was taken out from the document flow, right?

Comment: it will start after Comp1, only when you scroll your Comp1 will remain in its place, Comp2 will slide down it

Answer (score 0):

for fixed navbar you can add to comp1,

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and to have comp2 next to comp1, if you use `<div>` for your comp2 it will come next to comp1 automatically as div's are block elements default.